# un-synchronize an array from arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For a basic example

```
    int[] B;
    B=new int[4];
    B[0]=4;
    B[1]=3;
    B[2]=2;
    B[3]=1;
    ArrayList<int[]> C = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    C.add(B);
    B[0]=3;
    B[1]=2;
    B[2]=4;
    B[3]=1;
    C.add(B);
```

I have a basic array that I added to the list, I am changing the array B values as I go along in a loop which I wanted to add each new B from a loop to C but C is syncing with B automatically which prevent me from adding a new B. The reason I need a new B to be added is for tracking the progress of the loop and prevent duplication.

Currently C is always size of 1 with the new B.

Comment: Javascript is different from Java. I removed the tag. And also it's not eclipse specific problem.

Comment: As the Object is the same Object and it is mutable, then any change to the Object will be reflected in the ArrayList.  Most people would say that this is desired behaviour.  If want different then create a new Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a copy of the array instead:

```
C.add(Arrays.copyOf(B, B.length)); //or System#arraycopy
```

Java is pass by value of reference, an array is therefore pass by reference, and won't copy itself.

You should try to adhere to a common style guide (like Oracle/Google variable naming conventions).

Comment: Doesn't compile. Need a length parameter: `Arrays.copyOf(B, B.length)`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create a new array to hold the values you want, and add that:

```
int[] B;
B = new int[4];
B[0] = 4;
B[1] = 3;
B[2] = 2;
B[3] = 1;
ArrayList<int[]> C = new ArrayList<int[]>();
C.add(B);
int[] temp = new int[4];
temp[0] = 3;
temp[1] = 2;
temp[2] = 4;
temp[3] = 1;
C.add(temp);
```

I was going to suggest using `System.arraycopy`, but I don't think you need this as you don't need to actually copy any values from the `B` array.  If you are planning to do this in a loop, it is no problem as your temporary arrays will be cleaned up as they go out of scope.

Comment: because I am running as a loop which the array that would be in the list going to be alot

Comment: Then just create temporary arrays as you need them in the loop.  The garbage collector will do its job of cleaning up.